# How do recursive calls work (sierpinksi triangle)?

Tags: python, recursion

I came across a program that draws the Sierpinski Triangle with recursion. 
How I interpret this code is sierpinski1 is called until n == 0, and then only 3 small  triangles (one triangle per call) would be drawn because n == 0 is the only case when something is drawn (panel.canvas.create_polygon).  However, this is not how the code works because when run the number of triangles dependent upon n are drawn, not just the 3 small triangles I think would show.

Can someone explain to me how many things can be drawn when the function sierpinski1 only has 1 condition for when something can be drawn? That is the one part of the program that I can't understand. I looked up everything I could on recursion, but no information pertained to explaining why this format of recursion works.

```
def sierpinski(n):
    x1 = 250
    y1 = 120
    x2 = 400
    y2 = 380
    x3 = 100
    y3 = 380
    panel = DrawingPanel(500,500)
    sierpinski1(n,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,panel)

def sierpinski1(n,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,panel):
    if n == 0:
        panel.canvas.create_polygon(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3, fill = 'yellow', outline = 'black')
    else:
        sierpinski1(n-1,x1,y1,(x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2,(x1+x3)/2,(y1+y3)/2, panel)
        sierpinski1(n-1,(x1+x3)/2,(y1+y3)/2,(x2+x3)/2,(y2+y3)/2,x3,y3,panel)
        sierpinski1(n-1,(x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2,x2,y2,(x2+x3)/2,(y2+y3)/2,panel)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the principle of how recursion works:  there is a **base case** and there is a **recursive case**.  Since recursion makes use of a LIFO structure (such as a call stack), we have to know when to stop adding calls to the stack.

The base case:

- Occurs when `n == 0`
- Performs the actual drawing action
- Means that there are no more triangles to be generated, so it's okay to start drawing them.

The recursive case:

- Occurs when `n > 0` (and strictly speaking, when `n < 0`)
- Makes three distinct calls to itself, each with varying values for x1, x2, y1, and y2.
- Means that there are still more triangles to be generated.

Think of it like this. The number of triangles to be drawn is given by this formula T:

[image: T of x = 3 to the n if n is greater than 0, 0 otherwise.]

This holds for simple triangles:  If n = 1, then there's only three triangles drawn.  If n = 2, then 9 are drawn, and so forth.

**Why will it work?**  The **call stack** plays a big role in this.

For brevity, here's a trace of n = 1:

```
sierpinski1(n,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,panel)
    condition n = 0 FAILS
    sierpinski1(n-1,x1,y1,(x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2,(x1+x3)/2,(y1+y3)/2, panel)
        condition n = 0 PASSES
        panel.canvas.create_polygon(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3, fill = 'yellow', outline = 'black')
    sierpinski1(n-1,(x1+x3)/2,(y1+y3)/2,(x2+x3)/2,(y2+y3)/2,x3,y3,panel)
        condition n = 0 PASSES
        panel.canvas.create_polygon(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3, fill = 'yellow', outline = 'black')
    sierpinski1(n-1,(x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2,x2,y2,(x2+x3)/2,(y2+y3)/2,panel)
        condition n = 0 PASSES
        panel.canvas.create_polygon(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3, fill = 'yellow', outline = 'black')
```

So, for n = 1, there are exactly three lines drawn.  For higher values of `n`, things get trickier to see at a pseudocode high level, but the same principle applies.

Answer (score 1):

Things are only drawn when n = 0, but if it is called with n = 1, then three separate calls are made to it with n = 0. Similarly, if it is called with n = 2, then three calls are made to it with n = 1, each of which makes three calls to it with n = 0, for a total of nine drawings. In general, as the number of calls is multiplied by three each layer, there are 3^n small triangles drawn when it is called with n.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain to me how many things can be drawn when the
>   function sierpinski1 only has 1 condition for when something can be
>   drawn?

Because the function makes three recursive calls at each non-zero step.  That means for every `n` that is greater than 0, the function branches into three distinct paths whose value for `n` is smaller by 1.  You will end up reaching `n=0` a total number of **3<sup>n</sup>** times.